# Nancy Module Autodiscovering not Working after ILMerge

Tags: c#, nancy, ilmerge

Whe i run my Nancy selfhosted Application in Visual Studio everything works as expected but when i use ILMerge to create a allInOne.exe I just get 404s on every Url.

Thats the ILMerge command:

```
ILMerge.exe /target:console /out:allInOne.exe application.exe "Nancy.Hosting.Self.dll" "Nancy.dll"
```

The Problem is that none of the Modules are Autodiscovered and therefore no Routes are avalaible. 
The Problem also only occurs in the Merged Exe File. When i run the application.exe in /bin/release everything works.

best regards

Answer (score 1):

By default it will not scan the assembly that "Nancy" is in (which usually is Nancy.dll). Now that you've merged them it is going to exclude the entire merged assembly. You can change the behavior by overriding this method so that it doesn't exclude Nancy assembly (the `true` flag in the TypesOf call)

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/Bootstrapper/NancyBootstrapperBase.cs#L94

Comment: I made it .TypesOf<INancyModule>(ScanMode.All) but it still does not work. Any clues?

Comment: @TheCodeJunkie Can you explain more in details what to do?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I found two parts necessary. First, override the Modules property in your bootstrapper like Andreas suggested:

```
protected override IEnumerable<ModuleRegistration> Modules
{
    get
    {
        return
            AppDomainAssemblyTypeScanner
                    .TypesOf<INancyModule>(ScanMode.All)
                    .NotOfType<DiagnosticModule>()
                    .Select(t => new ModuleRegistration(t))
                    .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Second, when you create the Nancy host, use the overload which takes an instance of your bootstrapper:

```
using (var host = new NancyHost(new Bootstrapper(), new Uri(uri)))
{
    host.Start();
    // Do your thang
}
```

I was originally using the overload which only takes a Uri, but still couldn't hit my endpoints when running the ILMerged host. My guess is that Nancy also auto-discovers the *bootstrapper*, and will fail to find it as well if it's in Nancy's assembly.